# header, container, footer need to fit in any resolution without scroller

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6upkcet8/), header, container, footer need to fit in any resolution without scroller or is there any way to do it without using fixed position

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.content {
  background: yellow;
}
footer {
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <img src="http://www.emedicalpoint.com/images/nav/sprite.jpg" alt="">
</header>
<div class="content">
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </p>
</div>
<footer>
  footer content comes here
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag) inside the `<head>` tag:

   ```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
   ```

   This should make the page render at a reasonable size.
2. Add this `<style>` tag inside the `<head>` tag:

   ```
   <style>
   img {
       max-width: 100%;
   }
   </style>
   ```

   I *think* this will make sure all images don't render any wider than the app's webview's viewport.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, These are all basics which i did already but i would like to know wht about the middle content?, It should fit in screen . SO is there any way to do it ?